# Dual boot WIndows next to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, wine

I have some windows games/programs that won't run using Wine. So I want to install windows next to Ubuntu, without (of course) deleting Ubuntu.
I know that Mac has such a thing as Bootcamp, but how does this work for Ubuntu?

What I expect to be possible is something like this:
While in the boot screen, I want to be able to choose between Ubuntu and Windows XP.

I tried googling this, but honestly, I don't even know what to look for.

Comment: You don't know what to look for? How about [searching the title](http://google.com/search?q=Dual+boot+WIndows+next+to+Ubuntu) of your "question"?

Comment: @OlehPrypin You think I didn't try this?

Answer (score 0):

you are searching for a dual boot with windows 7? and ubuntu.

there are many "how to's" or tutorials for that.

one of them is here :

[dual boot](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot)

Comment: I need one with Windows XP, but like I commented on djxxwolfxx's answer: I already found another program called VirtualBox and it works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Either use Crossover or Wine.
Why? because it takes too much time just trying to do the dual boot, unless you're really that patient to do a dual boot.

Comment: In the meantime I found a program called VirtualBox. It works pretty good! But I will take a look at Crossover, since Wine doesn't do the job for me. Wine doesn't support enough programs/games in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

So, for those who are interested, this is what helped me:

[How to run Windows XP inside Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427/how-to-run-windows-xp-inside-ubuntu)

Of course, it will also work for different OS, but I was mainly interested in Windows XP.
After installing and setting up your VirtualBox, you either boot (in VirtualBox of course) from the CD you have for your preferred OS, or just use the .iso file if you downloaded it.

Open your Virtual computer by double clicking it and go to Devices to select how you want to install your OS.