# Install Windows 7 on separate partitions without losing grub

Tags: 12.10, windows-7, windows-8, grubrescue

I have Windows 8 installed on a separate partition which I want to replace with Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.10 installed on a separate partition. I want to do this without losing grub.

How should I do it?

Comment: Is system BIOS or UEFI? If BIOS based instruction posted will work. But if UEFI you need to convert Windows 7 installer to flash drive and also convert it to UEFI mode. Otherwise a Windows installer will auto convert entire drive to MBR and create all sorts of issues.

Answer (score 1):

- Open `gparted partition editor`,in ubuntu and delete the windows 8 partition and format it to `ntfs` filesystem.
- Download [`boot-repair live disk`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/) .iso file,and make a bootable boot-repair live usb.
- Insert windows 7 installation disk,and install windows 7 os on the deleted windows 8 partition.
- After that insert `boot-repair live usb` and boot from it.On startup click on the **Recommende repair** option.It will reinstall your grub.

Answer (score 0):

if u wont use windows often try to install it within virtual box , for reference goto

[how to install windows on ubuntu using wine](https://askubuntu.com/a/430/192102)

other wise for dual boot goto

[how to install windows after ubuntu for dual-boot](https://askubuntu.com/a/6321/192102)

hope it is what u want.. if i was u , i wud definitely go with second option for dual-boot..