# Is there a way to run Star Craft 2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: steam

I cant seem to find anything to run it - or the battle.net desktop which you need to launch Star Craft 2.

Can anyone tell me what i need to install? I have looked at some wine programs and I found one but its old and it might not work with the new void expansion.

Is there another emulator to run this game - and if so where do  get it?

[I asked here, and it wasn't much help.](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/7257017667)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, big Windows software, which requires various libraries and dependencies, are very tricky to run on Linux (with Wine or the like). I don't think it is possible to run starcraft2 decently without installing it on a virtual machine based on Virtualbox or VMware. The `seamless` mode makes the virtualbox very transparent.

Disclaimer: I haven't installed starcraft2 on a virtual machine myself. But I did try with many other Windows software.

Answer (score 0):

It will not run on Wine:

[Test results for Ubuntu 14.04](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20882&iTestingId=92321)

> **What does not work**
>
> Starting the game, crashes shortly after seeing the initial loading screen.
>
> **Additional Comments**
>
> Error from debug output:
>
> ```
> 4.exe: ../nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:359: __pthread_mutex_lock_full: Assertion `robust || (oldval & 0x40000000) == 0' failed.
> ```

So you have a couple of options:

- [Run Windows in a Virtualbox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427/how-to-run-windows-xp-inside-ubuntu). This is unrealistic unless you have an extremely good computer. I can run PowerPoint in Virtual box, but that takes 11GB of RAM to manage a 50 slide presentation with lots of images. I doubt you'd be able to run a GPU intensive game (OBS doesn't even work).
- [Dual boot Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6317/how-can-i-install-windows-after-ive-installed-ubuntu). This seems much more likely to work. You will need to partition the hard drive etc, so requires a backup.

Of course, both of these require Windows to be installed. I'd suggest [buying a Windows 7 OEM](https://softwaregeeks.co.uk/product/windows-7-home-premium-3264bit-product-key-coa/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwmKG5BRDv4YaE5t6oqf0BEiQAwqDNfGK7DI9j6OEWRzbMvbaQt2WT0ga9mL2i-7L_ufR6_ZkaAtyO8P8HAQ), and then updating it to Windows 10 if you wanted - a much cheaper option to buying Windows 10 for £99.