# Is Drobo5N2 Dashboard available for Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, nas

I am very new to Ubuntu. I am wondering if I can install Drobo Dashboard?

Comment: What's "Drobo Dashboard"? From where did you get it?

Answer (score 4):

[Drobo's download page](http://www.drobo.com/drobo-downloads-2/) only lists the software for Mac and Windows, so seemingly there's **no package available** for Ubuntu or any other Linux distribution. I suggest you [contact Drobo](https://supportportal.drobo.com) and let them know you miss a `.deb` package for their software, they'll listen if they care.
In the meantime you can run “Drobo Dashboard for Windows” in a virtual machine, see e.g. [How to run Windows XP inside Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427/how-to-run-windows-xp-inside-ubuntu).

Comment: Wine can't handle peripheral hardware except supported device classes recognised by Linux. (This isn't actual hardware support but use of system resources provided by the kernel and other subsystems like file systems, networking, X.org, ALSA, Pulseaudio, or CUPS).